# How to report the indices of a sub array whose xor is zero?

Tags: c++, arrays, xor

**Input array** : 5,2,7,100,1090,1,3,6,4,1062 (0-indexed array)

**Task** : For a given sequence of positive integers I want to find the number of triples (i,j,k) such that 1 ≤ i < j ≤ k ≤ N and

A[i]^…^A[j]−1=A[j]^A[j]+1^…^A[k],
where ^ denotes bit wise XOR.

I've already tried the problem using prefix_xor array and map in C++ but I still need to improve the time complexity.

```
cin >> n;
int A[n];
ll count = 0;
unordered_map<int, vector<int>> map_table;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cin >> A[i];
map_table[A[0]].push_back(0);
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
{
    A[i] = A[i] ^ A[i-1];
    if (!A[i])
        count += i;
    map_table[A[i]].push_back(i);
}
unordered_map<int, vector<int>>::iterator i2; 
for (i2 = map_table.begin(); i2 != map_table.end(); ++i2)
{
    int size = i2->second.size();
    if (size >= 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size-1; ++i)
        {
            for (int k = i+1; k < size; ++k)
                count += ((i2->second[k])-(i2->second[i])-1);
        }
    }
}
cout << count << '\n';
```

In this example the answer is 20

[0,2], [5,8], [0,9], [3,9]

XOR(5, 2, 7) = 0; XOR(1, 3, 6, 4) = 0; XOR(100, 1090, .... 1062) = 0; XOR(5, 2, 7 .... 1062) = 0

Comment: `int A[n];`  -- Invalid C++.  You're already using `std::vector`, so why not here also?  `std::vector<int> A(n);`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that's a different question, Can u please answer my question

Comment: You're new here. The comment section is for comments, not for answers.  Second, once you write nested loops like this: `for (int i = 0; i < size-1; ++i) { for (int k = i+1; k < size; ++k)`, you are going in the wrong direction.

Comment: yes I'm new here

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know about that nested loop but how do I report the indices then ?

Comment: My point is that the loop is `O(n*n)`.  If you are aware of that, then that is what you should be attempting to improve.  If you got this question from one of those "online judge" websites, these sites are notorious for giving questions that makes the programmer give the naïve, slow solutions.  They're looking for you to think outside the box and come up with a solution that isn't naïve / slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to be optimizing this part of your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size-1; ++i)
{
    for (int k = i+1; k < size; ++k)
        count += ((i2->second[k])-(i2->second[i])-1);
}
```

Note that you're basically trying to find the sum of the differences between every pair of numbers in an array (`i2->second`). You're doing this in `O(n^2)`, but if we manipulate the formulas a bit we can do it faster.

Let's say our array, which we'll call `a` for now, has length `n`. We'll only focus on the `i`th element (0-indexed) for now, and we'll count the total number of times it gets added to and subtracted from the sum. For every `j < i`, the total sum will include `a[i] - a[j]`. Similarly, for every `j > i`, the total sum includes `a[j] - a[i]`. In the former case, `a[i]` is added a total of `i` times. In the latter case, `a[i]` is subtracted a total of `n - i - 1` times. So the coefficient of `a[i]` in the total sum (number of times it's added minus number of times it's subtracted) is `i - (n - i - 1) == 2 * i - n + 1`. Multiplying this by every element and adding everything up gives us the answer (after adjusting for the `-1` part).

Now for the complexity, this algorithm will be `O(n)` for one prefix XOR value where `n` is the number of times that value occurs. Since the number of times each prefix XOR value occurs will sum to the length of the original array, the total complexity is linear after the map is created.

Here's an example as requested:

Let's say the array has five elements, `a[0...4]`. If we write out the sum you're trying to compute, it looks like this:

```
  (a[1] - a[0]) + (a[2] - a[0]) + (a[3] - a[0]) + (a[4] - a[0])
+ (a[2] - a[1]) + (a[3] - a[1]) + (a[4] - a[1])
+ (a[3] - a[2]) + (a[4] - a[2])
+ (a[4] - a[3])
```

We'll deal with the `-1`'s later. If we group like terms, it looks like this:

```
-4 * a[0] + -2 * a[1] + 0 * a[2] + 2 * a[3] + 4 * a[4]
```

Notice that the coefficient of a term is related to the index of that term by the formula mentioned above. So instead of iterating over every pair of elements, we compute this shortened expression. In the original problem, you need to subtract one for every pair of elements, so we can just subtract the number of pairs of elements from the result.

Comment: Can u provide the code or at least explain with the help of an example ?

Comment: I cannot understand this part "we'll count the total number of times it gets added to and subtracted from the sum"

Comment: @ObiWanKenobi I added an example.